# Dagger2 Provider in koin

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, koin

Is there any alternative to javax.inject.Provider in koin?

To react to actions, I am injecting Commands to my activity.
Command is a single-run object, for example WriteToFile.

In dagger I could make it like this:

```
class MainPresenter : Presenter() {

  @Inject
  lateinit var writeFile: Provider<WriteFileCommand>

  fun onSaveClicked() {
    writeFile.get().run()
  }
}
```

in koin, when I try to use:

```
class MainPresenter : Presenter() {

  lateinit var writeFile: Provider<WriteFileCommand> by inject()

  fun onSaveClicked() {
    writeFile.get().run()
  }
}
```

My koin module:

```
val appModule = module {
  factory { WriteFileCommand(get(), get()) }
  factory { FileProvider() }
  single { DataStore() }
}
```

Than I got error saying:

> Can't create definition for 'Factory [name='WriteFileCommand',class='com.test.WriteFileCommand']' due to error :
>           No compatible definition found. Check your module definition

I understand that I can call:

```
var command: WriteFileCommand = StandAloneContext.getKoin().koinContext.get()
command.run()
```

But It looks so cumbersome

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far as well as your setup and simplified modules. So far the question is too broad. Do you have an issue with the injection itself? Do you have an issue with the definition of the dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing like a provider directly. If you use `inject`, you'll use a lazy delegate. If you use `get`, you'll create a new instance you declared the dependency with a `factory`. So `get` is what you need in your case. Just let your `MainPresenter` implement `KoinComponent` and you'll be able to use `get` directly:

```
class MainPresenter : Presenter(), KoinCompontent {
  fun onSaveClicked() = get<WriteFileCommand>().run()
}
```